# Restricting remote communication in Git

Tags: linux, git, ssh

I have Git installed in our company's Linux server. All the developers work on the same server. Recently we had to move to Git, which is hosted on some other server. Before we create a Git repository we create SSH keys and then start `ssh-agent` and finally add the private key using `ssh-add`.

My problem is I created a Git repository in the Linux machine, set my keys and everything and also did a push to remote Git server. But if some other developer also has his key added he can also perform a `git push` on my local repository.

Is there any way I can restrict push by other developers on the same Linux machine?

Comment: Do you need to restrict access to the repo or the server itself?

Comment: restrict push to server

Comment: Is every developer using the same account on the Linux server?

Comment: yes every one uses the same account

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent others from pushing to your personal development machine, set up a firewall. If you want to prevent people from pushing to remote server, remove their keys, or add per-ip firewall rules (so that they can still use SSH). At least that's what I'd do, since it looks like the git itself doesn't offer any access control facilities and leaves it to the OS/networking layer.

In any case, my opinion is that rather than setting up some security facilities, you should trust your coworkers not to screw things up. After all, it's not some public repository - it's a company, where screw ups (intentional or not) should be dealt with accordingly.